# How do I get a Falloff offset matrix to look like it's coming from a single point?

Tags: animation-nodes

In my example file the LEGO car looks like it's being assembled from a central point and it's okay when it's relatively close in size to the icosphere I am using as a prop.

[image]

**Relatively close in size**

[image]

You can see here the objects are in the models final structure

[image]

It does not look so good when the model being assembled is much larger than the icosphere prop. The pieces come from a much wider range.

**Relatively large**

[image]

I've tried to adjust initial transforms but then I loose my desired built model.

My question is how can I maintain the same effect of the model being assembled and the pieces are coming from a single point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting the initial position of the objects from the offset vector should do what you want, it is also non-destructive, so it might be better than your original solution:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank @Omar, that's exactly what I was looking for. I tried to find exactly that online but if you don't know the right question to ask it gets difficult. :)

Answer (score 1):

Far too often I figure out the answer to my own questions:

First select all the objects and SHIFT+C -> Cursor to Selected, then SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+C -> Origin to 3D Cursor. Note if you want to have a selection order you have to set it up before this point.

Your object origins will go from

[image]

to

[image]

Now update your Initial Transforms and all the objects come from a single point :)

[image]